# Make a JavaScript randomizer where the consumer choose items from a list, that later become randomized

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a randomizer in JavaScript but can't get it to work. 
So I have an array, which I want the consumer to pick from, for example 3 different items, then randomizing ur pick.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you describe your question in more detail and attach the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
array=["a","b","c","d"]; 
 result=[1,2,3].map(()=>array[Math.floor(Math.random()*(array.length))]);
```

This picks three random items.
http://jsbin.com/xihojufabi/edit?console

Comment: I meant that I'd create a list of, let's say my 10 favorite movies. And then someone else choose 2 or more from this list. But it randomizes what you that guy chose.

Comment: @EmilAvara just code the choosing part that pushes the answers onto an array, than execute my code...